# Internet/Wifi/MobileData not working on android emulator (MacOS M1)

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator

When running android emulator on MacOS with M1 chip, neither emulator wifi or mobile data seems to work.
Connection says `No internet` on the dropdown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Mac OS go to:
**System Preferences -> Network -> select Wi-Fi os left panel -> Advanced on right panel -> DNS -> add new DNS server; for example 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 (Google Public DNS)**

Answer (score 9):

## Alternative solution

If you are in a corporate network where it is not possible to change the dns of your mac (Losing access to company resources), we can follow the following steps in the **emulator** (Yes, in the started emulator):

1. Go to settings.
2. Select networks and internet.
3. Touch Wi-Fi.
4. Select the default network (usually AndroidWifi).
5. Edit the connection (In API 33 it is the pencil at the top right).
6. Change the IP settings to **Manual** with the following:

> - IP address: **10.0.2.16**
> - Gateway: **10.0.2.2**
> - Network prefix: **24**
> - DNS1: **8.8.8.8** <--- The same one that they ask you to put on your mac
> - DNS2: **8.8.4.4**

Select **save** and proceed to disconnect and reconnect the network.

Problem solved!

Comment: This worked for me but I had to do a power Shutdown in the Emulator and start it again for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for Macbook only

```
Step 1
Turn off wifi on your macbook laptop

Step 2
Close / Quit your emulator in android studio

Step 3
Cool Boot your emulator

Step 4
Open your emulator and connect your emulator to wifi(at this point of time your laptop is not connected to wifi yet)

Step 4
Now connect your macbook laptop to wifi.

Step 5
You will see your emulator is connected to wifi and its able to access internet now
```

Comment: I can confirm this is the only solution that worked as of 2024 (Android Studio Jellyfish + Android Emulator v34)

Answer (score -1):

First, close your virtual device.

Mac(ventura)
If you are connected by Ethernet, make this:
Go to System Preferences -> Network -> Ethernet -> Details -> DNS -> Click on + button -> add: 8.8.8.8(don't forget points), again + button and add 8.8.4.4

Finally press on OK button and enjoy, now you can launch again your virtual device.